# Mysql function error - unable to figure it out

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

Please help me with Mysql Function. Code:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE FUNCTION `media`.`Return_Next_Season`(
        season VARCHAR(200) )
    RETURNS VARCHAR
    DECLARE _ids INT ;
    DECLARE _bsk VARCHAR(200);


SELECT id INTO _ids  FROM media._broadcast_seasons WHERE broadcast_season_key = '20132014_Fall';



SELECT broadcast_season_key INTO bsk FROM media._broadcast_seasons WHERE id  = ids;

    RETURN bsk;
    BEGIN

    END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: what is the error stack?

Comment: Can you show your table(s) schema? Your two selects don't make any sense. And you don't use `season` parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Do you think it's a good idea having that `BEGIN` *after* all the code that does something useful? :-) Or, in less obtuse language, move the `BEGIN` to just after the `RETURNS VARCHAR`, something like (`select` statements broken up for readability but you may have to recombine them):

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE FUNCTION `media`.`Return_Next_Season`(
    season VARCHAR(200) )
    RETURNS VARCHAR(200)
    BEGIN
        DECLARE _ids INT ;
        DECLARE _bsk VARCHAR(200);
        SELECT id INTO _ids  FROM media._broadcast_seasons
            WHERE broadcast_season_key = '20132014_Fall';
        SELECT broadcast_season_key INTO bsk FROM media._broadcast_seasons
            WHERE id  = ids;
        RETURN bsk;
    END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

You'll notice I've also changed the return type to give it a size since I believe that's necessary as well.

Comment: tried this.. doesnt work..

Error Code : 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'BEGIN DECLARE _ids INT ; DECLARE _bsk VARCHAR(200); SELE' at line 4

share|edit|delete|flag

Comment: @user3128161, I think that's to do with the return type missing an upper size length. Try it with the updated code, `returns varchar(200)`.